# ExtJS wait until all models has been loaded

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a `setTimeout` in my ExtJS 4.2.1 Application that has to be triggered until all models in a `store.each` function are loaded:

```
checkProcessStatus: function() {
        console.log('check pending process status');
        var me = this,
            grid = me.getRequestGrid(),
            store = grid.getStore();

        //var inprocess = [];

        // get all pending processes
        store.each(function(rec) {
            if (rec.get('Status') == 0 || rec.get('Status') == 1) {
                //inprocess.push(rec);

                var id = rec.get('RequestProcessId');
                // has to check the status of each record
                var model = me.getCalculationRequestProcessModel(); // Ext.create('RequestProcessModel');
                model.getProxy().extraParams = {
                    requestProcessId: id
                };
                model.load(id, {
                    success: function(record, operation) {

                        var recToUpdate = store.getById(id);

                        // only if the status has changed then update grid
                        if (recToUpdate.get('Status') != record.get('Status')) {

                            recToUpdate.set(record.getData());

                            // refresh grid node
                            grid.getView().refreshNode(store.indexOfId(id));

                        }

                    }
                });


            }
        });

       // if all models were loaded correctly then call my timer function
       // run timer
       me.timer = setTimeout(Ext.bind(me.checkProcessStatus, me), 5000);


    },
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: For clarification : why would you load record by record instead of loading all at once ?

Comment: I only want to load records that has an specific value. I could have 30 records but just 3 are pending to process (status =0 or 1)

Comment: Is there a reason why using a store [filter](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filterBy) to limit the store records isn't an option?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a good solution:

I create an empty array:

```
var pendingRecs = [];
var totalPending = 0;
```

Then I loop the store and push the match record into the `pendingRecs` array:

```
store.each(function(rec) {
            if (rec.get('Status') == 0 || rec.get('Status') == 1) {
                // add only the processes that are pending or inpgrogress
                pendingRecs.push(rec);
            }
        });
```

Then I set the totalPending var:

```
totalPending = pendingRecs.length;
```

Then I run a for statement:

```
for (i = 0; i < pendingRecs.length; i++) {

            var rec = pendingRecs[i];

      // do stuff

      // load model

                  model.load(id, {

            success: function(record, operation) {

                var recToUpdate = store.getById(id);

                // only if the status has changed then update grid
                if (recToUpdate.get('Status') != record.get('Status')) {

                    recToUpdate.set(record.getData());

                    // refresh grid node
                    grid.getView().refreshNode(store.indexOfId(id));

                }

                totalPending--;
                // if this is the last record then run the timer again
                if (totalPending== 0) {

                    pendingRecs = null;
                    // run timer
                    me.timer = setTimeout(Ext.bind(me.checkProcessStatus, me), 5000);
                }

            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you may be contented with the solution you found, I do not think it is an optimal one. Let me explain why.

You need (at least) one request to initially load records to `store`. Then you iterate through all these records to cherry-pick those that need "further processing" and you load them one-by-one from the server executing the processing in `success` callback.

Now, why must server deliver all records when only some of the need processing? If Ext can decide what are the records for processing so the server can.

Then, knowing the additional records for processing, why not load all of them in one request? (Note: It is really worth to save number of server requests as that is one of the main reason the feeling that the application is sluggish.)

Again, server can test which records to deliver for further processing.